# Docker - Cannot start Redis Service

Tags: redis, docker

I'm installation `Redis`, setting up `init.d`, placed the `redis.conf` beside `init.d`.

Then using `CMD service init.d start` to start `Redis`.

However, `Redis-Server` does not start, and there are no indiciation in the log file that the service failed to start.

1. Installing `Redis` and Placing `redis.conf` to the `etc/init.d` folder

Commands:

```
# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN groupadd -r redis && useradd -r -g redis redis

RUN apt-get update  > /dev/null \
    && apt-get install -y curl > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* > /dev/null 2>&1

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
RUN gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4
RUN curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && gpg --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc  > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc  > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu  > /dev/null 2>&1

ENV REDIS_VERSION 3.0.1
ENV REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.1.tar.gz
ENV REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA1 fe1d06599042bfe6a0e738542f302ce9533dde88

# for redis-sentinel see: http://redis.io/topics/sentinel
RUN buildDeps='gcc libc6-dev make'; \
     set -x \
    && apt-get update > /dev/null && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/redis > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && curl -sSL "$REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL" -o redis.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && echo "$REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA1 *redis.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c - > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && tar -xzf redis.tar.gz -C /usr/src/redis --strip-components=1 > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && rm redis.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && make -C /usr/src/redis > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && make -C /usr/src/redis install > /dev/null 2>&1 \
   && cp /usr/src/redis/utils/redis_init_script /etc/init.d/redis_6379
    && rm -r /usr/src/redis > /dev/null 2>&1 \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps > /dev/null 2>&1

RUN mkdir /data && chown redis:redis /data
VOLUME [/data]
WORKDIR /data
```

2. `CMD Service init.d start`

Command:

```
RUN touch /var/redis/6379/redis-6379-log.txt
RUN chmod 777 /var/redis/6379/redis-6379-log.txt
ENV REDISPORT 6379
ADD $app$/redis-config.txt /etc/redis/$REDISPORT.conf
CMD service /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start
```

---

If I use shellinabox to access the container, and if I type in

> /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start

Redis server will start, but it won't start in the dockerfile. Why is this?

---

It seems that you cannot use background processes, but instead you need something called supervisord.

To Install:

```
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD $app$/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord
```

Configuration File:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:shellinabox]
command=/bin/bash -c "cd /tmp && exec /opt/shellinabox/shellinaboxd --no-beep --service ${service}"

[program:redis-server]
command=/bin/bash -c "redis-server /etc/redis/${REDISPORT}.conf"
```

What happens is that after the command is executed, it will start both programs shelllinabox and redis-server.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Make sure you run program in foreground mode (no-daemon). Please take a look at the official redis dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't use an `init` script inside a Docker container.  These scripts are typically designed to start a service "in the background", which means that even if the service starts, the script ultimately exits.

If this is the first process in your Docker container, Docker will see it exit, which will cause it to clean up the container.  You will need to arrange for `redis` to run in the foreground in your container, or you will need to arrange to run some sort of process supervisor in your container.

Consider looking at the [official resource container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/) to see one way of setting things up.  You can see the Dockerfiles in the [github repository](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/redis).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm very new to docker, if I set daemon mode to no, can I just to RUN redis-server /etc/redis/$REDISPORT.conf & in the docker file instead? I'm trying to create my own stack, that setups up different types servers in a dockerfile.

Comment: Maybe that's not the way docker is supposed to be used? :S

Comment: Well, that is pretty much what the official redis container does.  `CMD [ "redis-server" ]`

Comment: it sounds like you can only have 1 CMD in a dockerfile? I'm trying to use RUN instead, would that work?

Comment: You can only have one `CMD` in a Dockerfile.  `RUN` is for running commands as part of the `docker build` process.

Comment: Is there a way to run the redis-server without the & or daemon, then later on run some code in the same docker file that interfaces with the redis-server? Because if I run it with redis-server <some_config> it gets stuck (I think it's because it's trying to wait until redis-server exits).

Comment: use supervisor if you want to deal with more than one process, https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ or a similar tool like runit or s6 or daemontools https://docs.docker.com/faq/

Comment: That is what I was suggesting when I mentioned "process supervisors". However, it is often a more flexible design to place your initialization code in another container. This lets you keep your container design simple and is more flexible in environments where you are scaling containers.

Comment: @larsks, user2915097 I got it! Thanks! I've been trying supervisord and it works perfectly.